# Pass stream to function

Tags: function, recursion, ostream

```
vector<bool> retroswap (vector<bool> v)
 {
     reverse(v.begin(), v.end()) ;
     for (int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
     {
         if (v[i] == 0)
         {
             v[i] = 1 ;
         } else {
             v[i] = 0 ;
         }
     }
     v.insert(v.begin(), 1) ;

     return v ;
 }

// Overloading the + operator
vector<bool> operator+ (vector<bool> gds, vector<bool> rs)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rs.size() ; i++)
    {
        gds.push_back(rs[i]) ;
    }

    return gds ;
}


ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, vector<bool> v)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
    {
        out << v[i] << endl ;
    }

    return out ;
}

vector<bool> generate_dragon_sequence (vector<bool> v, int n, ostream& out)
 {
     if (n==1)
     {
         return v ;
     }

     vector<bool> rs = retroswap(generate_dragon_sequence(v, n-1, out)) ;

     out << generate_dragon_sequence(v, n-1, out) + rs ;

     return generate_dragon_sequence(v, n-1, out) + rs ;

 }
```

Above is my code that i am doing for my school project. I have a question regarding passing ostream objects to functions. I am constructing a recursive function which generates larger and larger vectors according to an algorithm. All I want to do is to output the final vector product using the stream object

Hence, in int main(), if I were to write generate_dragon_function(v, n, cout), it will output the final vector to the console.

I was wondering how I could do it? Thank you so much guys!